# How do we force DX to push items that it doesn't think are updated?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

I'm building a DX project now, and every time I try to push some fields, `force:source:push` fails to recognize that the fields are an addition. I've tried deleting the source files, pushing, and then adding it back, editing properties in it, as well as creating a new artifact folder, putting the files in there, pushing, then moving it back to where I want it. Each time, the net result is that my scratch org ends up without the field in play, yet I can't get the field to push. Is there some file I can modify, or command argument, that will allow me to force this field to be pushed correctly? Even better, is there a way to force a recalculation of the artifacts so that I can get everything back in sync, since I don't even know what's missing from my org at this point? I have approximately 24,000 files to go through, so manual checking is a futile effort at best.

---

## Additional Info

When this bug occurs, `force:source:status` does not show that the file is created or modified, even after modifying the attributes of the field or moving it to a new file path then moving it back.

Editing `.sfdx/orgs/<username>/sourcePathInfos.json` to modify the file attributes or remove the entry completely have no effect on resolving this bug.

I have had *some* luck deleting the contents of `.sfdx/orgs/`, but then I typically end up with lots of errors about duplicate relationship names and lots of other errors.

What's really odd about it is that sometimes, I can add *another* file, since I'm spoonfeeding DX about 10-20 files at a time between each push, and the previously bugged out fields will *show* that they were added, but logging in to the scratch org, they still don't exist. At that point, they won't push again.

Ultimately, this question is to try and find the most foolproof, easiest way to resync the file system with the scratch org.

---

[Demo Repo](https://github.com/brianmfear/demo-repo) that demonstrates the problem. Readme includes instructions, but basically involves doing something like this:

```
$ git clone https://https://github.com/brianmfear/demo-repo.git
$ cd demo-repo
$ sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json -a demo-repo -v DevHub
$ sfdx force:source:push
```

At this point, you'll see the following output:

```
STATE  FULL NAME                 TYPE         PROJECT PATH
─────  ────────────────────────  ───────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Add    Account.Invalid_Field__c  CustomField  force-app\main\default\objects\Account\fields\Invalid_Field__c.field-meta.xml
Add    Account.Valid_Field__c    CustomField  force-app\main\default\objects\Account\fields\Valid_Field__c.field-meta.xml


=== Push Errors
PROJECT PATH                                                                   ERROR
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
force-app\main\default\objects\Account\fields\Invalid_Field__c.field-meta.xml  Field Missing_Field__c does not exist. Check spelling. (3:13)
```

So, to fix it, let's say we delete `Invalid_Field__c`:

```
$ rm force-app/main/default/Account/fields/Invalid_Field__c.field-meta.xml
```

Then try to push again:

```
$ sfdx force:source:push -u demo-repo

=== Pushed Source
STATE    FULL NAME                 TYPE         PROJECT PATH
───────  ────────────────────────  ───────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Deleted  Account.Invalid_Field__c  CustomField  force-app\main\default\objects\Account\fields\Invalid_Field__c.field-meta.xml
```

Note that the invalid field was deleted (but erroneously not marked as a local deletion, because it doesn't exist on the server), and the other remaining field doesn't exist.

Now, you need to clear the cache to fix it...

```
$ rm -r .sfdx/orgs/*
$ sfdx force:source:push -u demo-repo

=== Pushed Source
STATE  FULL NAME               TYPE         PROJECT PATH
─────  ──────────────────────  ───────────  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Add    Account.Valid_Field__c  CustomField  force-app\main\default\objects\Account\fields\Valid_Field__c.field-meta.xml
```

Comment: Though I haven't come across this scenario and was able to push any file changed locally (which should be the expected behavior in your scenario as well), the documentation mentions *At this point, we start change-tracking locally on the file system and remotely in the scratch org to determine which metadata has changed.* Not sure if it could be the volume of the files (24K). Are you able to get the difference between local and scratch using the status (*force:source:status*)?

Comment: That's really interesting. And if it does not show any changed status, then most likely that's why it does not ever pushes any changes to the scratch org. Have you tried with just a few files, say 5-10 to start with, just to get an idea if volume is something that is causing this issue here? Worth circling it with Salesforce support. Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think it's a volume issue. We're dealing with this same issue this morning with reports and dashboards and we only have ~100 components in this package. Our issue might be slightly different because the folders had been in the .forceignore file, but after removing them from this file they are still not being pushed up and changes are not being reflected. (It's worth noting this *was* working yesterday just fine.)

Comment: What @RobertWatson mentioned, is it possible that all the previous failures on the fields as you mentioned [*previously bugged out fields will show that they were added, but logging in to the scratch org, they still don't exist*] were added to the .forceignore file?

Comment: @JayantDas .forceignore is the default that comes with `force:project:create` (ignores `package.xml`). Nothing else is in there.

Comment: That's what I had thought. I still think this has something to do with the the way the *push* is executed where internally a *status* precedes it. And that during the *status* execution, it kind of times/errors out, and never pushes changes to scratch. And it does not look like that the execution of the *push* follows **fail-fast** philosophy, rather commits partially (locally and not in the org). Because, if running the push again identifies fields to be present in scratch org, looks like somewhere the results are captured and utilized in the next run during the *status* execution.

Comment: @JayantDas Yeah, it seems broken. I'm just trying to get a more manageable push strategy for every time this thing goes sideways, which seems to be several times a day.

Comment: All I can say is you're not alone. I haven't had failures that big, but on a team of 3, about once every week or two we run into a scenario where some component silently failed to push or pull and won't resync without a manual edit/unedit. It would be REALLY nice if we had a syntax for "c'mon, sync this ONE FILE dammit!"

Comment: How can we get more traction on this question? I haven't had this happen to me since the day this question was posted but I would love to know something was being worked on here... is it worth connecting with someone at Salesforce on this? Wade Wegner?

Comment: @RobertWatson If you can get a hold of Wade, so much the better. I can't even describe how many hundreds of hours I've wasted on this defect so far.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this.  If this is still happening, please let me know. As for the ONE FILE dammit! we are working on new commands to allow that.

Comment: @DaveCarroll Demo repo has been uploaded with instructions, also replicated here with additional output details. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will investigate this further. While not citing this as the cause, I would suggest making sure your permsets reflect what ever **new source** you push.

Comment: I can confirm that this is a bug. @sfdxfox, thanks for the easily reproducible demo.  Will be filing a bug for this issue.

Comment: Now that SFDX is a thing, I find my fingers often typing "sfdx" when I meant to type "sfdc" too ;-)

Comment: @RobertWatson I'm halfway tempted to change my moniker to sfdxfox, lol.

Comment: I need a like button

Comment: @DaveCarroll You said you were filing a bug for this issue - is there somewhere we can watch that to know when it is fixed?

Comment: @RobertWatson - The best place to "watch" is the weekly release notes for the CLI. https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/releasenotes.html

It looks like this will be fixed in the next week or so.