# sfdx:source:push with partial success fails to recognise failed components on next push

Tags: salesforcedx

When **`sfdx:source:push`** command succeeds with partial success, i.e. few of the components in the payload failed to deploy, next time when I run **`sfdx:source:status`** command, it doesn't show me the failed components as missing in the scratch org, it assumes everything got pushed to the scratch org and there is nothing else to add.

I've to deploy everything again by deleting the contents of `.sfdx`  hidden folder to deploy failed components.

Is this an SFDX bug or am I missing something?

Comment: [`sfdx force:source:status`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm) has few optional parameters like all, local, remote, log level, etc. Give running the command with appropriate parameters.

Comment: Salesforce is [aware of the issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/215576). For now, I think you're meant to use force:source:deploy to force updates back to a scratch org, but if you still want to sync the way things should be, you'll have to deal with clearing the .sfdx folder.